Authenticate end-users of Google Cloud Run REST apis
I am trying to call Cloud Run service(requires authentication) endpoint. The user is public end-user which is authenticated through Firebase. Have researched and tried some of the guides to no avail. I Am also getting confused with the number of use cases of Cloud run service authentication.

The authenticated firebase user has Cloud Run admin role.
I Am getting 401 Unauthorized error
Should d Cloud run service be set as 'Allow unauthenticated'? (As of now, I have set it as 'Requires authentication')


3A (Yes), then I will have to authenticate all rest api calls inside individual endpoints? Or something like API Gateway?



3A.1 - Authenticate all rest api calls individually



3A.2 - API Gateway



In terms of pricing, would it be better to use 3A.1, because as I understand it correctly, 3A.2 will incur charges for authenticating users through it. 



It's just that it seems too primitive that 3A.1 would have to be done in each endpoint. Am I missing something? 




3B (No), then how come Cloud Run admin role user still gets 401 Unauthorised error.


One of the guides I saw, https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/authenticating/end-users ... states that the service should be set as public, does it mean Allow unauthenticated? See number 2 in image below.


4A - So, if it is Unauthenticated, then I would have to do 3A?


Thanks in advance.
PS: I am not that familiar with GCP.

Have a look at this Troubleshooting Documentation and Stackoverflow Link.

As per these sources, I would have to opt with 3A.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/64597885/7888262
https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/tutorials/identity-platform


Deploy the container image to Cloud Run using the console or CLI. Note that the server is deployed to allow unauthenticated access. This is so that the user can load the client and begin the process. The server verifies the id token added to the vote request manually, authenticating the end-user.


https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/authenticating/end-users


Deploy your Cloud Run service publicly.


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
